# Regex: Match word containing special characters

Tags: regex, match, special-characters, regex-negation, oniguruma

I am currently using a oniguruma regex to search for function like matches with the exception of some keywords. Ex, in the string
"this is a test() and im() testing() thi[s]()  this_[is]_a_fun(with,some,params)"

the regex should match:
`test`,
`im`,
`testing`,
`thi[s]`
`this_[is]_a_fun`
The current regex I'm using is

```
\s*([A-z0-9\w_]+).?(?=\()(\b(?<!if|while|for|return|else|elif|equals|or|xor|and|not|le|gre))
```

but this does not match `thi[s]` or any function containing brackets in the word.

I tried to update the regex to match these patterns with the regex

```
\s*([A-z0-9\w_|\[|\]]+).?(?=\()(\b(?<!if|while|for|return|else|elif|equals|or|xor|and|not|le|gre))
```

but to no avail.

Any help to match these kind of patterns would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this RegEx:

```
([\w+\[\]]+)(?=\([\w+,]*\))
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/EqxDYZ/1)
Details:

- `\w+` matches any word character (equal to [a-zA-Z0-9_]) one or more times
- `\[` matches the character `[` literally
- `\]` matches the character `]` literally
- `+` matches 1 or more times
- Positive Lookahead `(?=\([\w+,]*\))`  matches the characters `(` and  any characters from `[\w+,]` and the
  character `)` literally.
- `[\w+,]*` matches any word character (equal to [a-zA-Z0-9_]) and `,` zero or more times.

Comment: @Bohemian `$` matches the start of input, or start of a line in multiline mode.

Comment: @PedroRodrigues no, the opposite: `$` matches *end* of input, or *end* of line in multi line

Comment: @Bohemian you're correct. I meant `^`. Why your first question then?? And why not correct me in your last, instead of simply pointing the error?

Comment: This regex works for strings like "test()" but not if parameters are in the parenthesis like "test(with,params)". And I changed the regex to `\s*([a-zA-Z\[\]_]+).*(?=\()`
,which did work, until I tried to exlude the key words using this regex  `\s*([a-zA-Z\[\]_]+).*(?=\()(\b(?<!if|while|for|return|else|elif|equals|or|xor|and|not|le|gre))` but that did not capture the [], i think its due to the \b but idk

Comment: @Custards1 Updated the answer to match the new string.